# Team System 2008 and VS 2005 code

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

Our company is transitioning code from VS 2005.  I know they won't be able to use VS 2008 to access it, but we have the patch to enable web access for TFS 2008 applied to our TFS server.  This means they can access the source code via the web, but do the work in VS 2005.

The code will eventually be rewritten in VS 2008, but we need to maintain the legacy code with a source control tool.  SVN is not an acceptable solution as we are a .NET team system house.

Does anyone see any issues with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

VS2005 works great with TFS2008, the only thing to watch out for is in the area of Team Build where you might want a couple of VS2008 clients installed around to help you administer the builds.  VS2008 and VS2005 can live happily side by side on the same machine.

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your statement that you're "transitioning code"... VS2008 doesn't change any code in a VS2005 project/solution, just the project/solution files. Why are you moving to VS2008 only for some of your people? Seems better to have everyone move to VS2008. I doubt any of your developers will have any complaints moving to VS2008 unless they're running old hardware or something.

Answer (score 0):

We have done several upgrades from 2005 to 2008 and have had no real problems.  Just open the solution in 2008 and let it do the upgrade.  Then create a new project in TFS and add the upgraded source code to it.  We keep the old TFS project and source code around for reference purposes, but we've rarely actually needed to go back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you hear that VS2005 can't work with TFS 2008, and that VS2008 won't open VS2005 projects?  Like sliderhouserules said, only the project files are changed, and even then not in a way that VS 2005 can't open them.

I always test new tools when they come out, and with VS2008 I was able to run it side by side with the other dev's in my department and they never knew.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm....I don't want the project to convert.  It was mentioned that they want to use TFS to do the source control, but not migrate the project to 2008.  I wanted to get a sense of being about to use TFS 2008 with a 2005 project.

I know I can run 2.0 framework in 2008.  I just don't want it converting it to 2008 yet since we have plans to re-write the application.  I'll try to open the solution up again without upgrading it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a build in TFS08?   I recall seeing an posting saying that the build order in SLN was not being respected by the build.  I think the suggestion was to specify the projects themselves to build.